# Difference between shared_dynamic_cast and dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Can someone explain to me the difference between:

`shared_dynamic_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` from the Boost library?

It appears to me that they may be equivalent.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given a `shared_ptr<T>`, the two functions are indeed equivalent.

The difference is that `shared_dynamic_cast` *only* works with `shared_ptr<>`'s, while `dynamic_pointer_cast` works with any kind of pointer (via overloading). This enables you to perform a dynamic cast on any pointer *concept*, regardless of how that pointer is actually composed:

```
#include <boost/pointer_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct foo {};
struct bar : foo { void f(){} };

template <typename Ptr>
void test(Ptr ptr)
{
    boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<bar>(ptr)->f();
}

int main()
{
    bar b;
    foo* pf = &b;

    std::shared_ptr<foo> spf(new bar());

    test(pf); // turns into dynamic_cast<bar*>(pf)->f();
    test(spf); // turns into shared_dynamic_cast<bar>(pf)->f();
}
```

Because `dynamic_pointer_cast` has the capability of `shared_dynamic_cast` and more, **the latter function is deprecated**. (Likewise in C++11, there only exists `dynamic_pointer_cast`.)

(The idea is the same for the other cast variants too, of course.)

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question to correct the type name! Lazy typing...!

Comment: Ok, digging a bit deeper it appears that:
`// shared_*_cast names are deprecated. Use *_pointer_cast instead.` so there you go! Update your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Nick: Huh, I didn't know that. Now I have to wonder whether that's the case because C++11 only has `dynamic_pointer_cast`, or if C++11 only has that cast because of Boost. Oh well.